# Create MySQL table for Team that is always changing

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in the middle of creating my first WAMP stack website (teaching myself as I build it) and I'm getting hung up on the logic for my database. The website will essentially keep track of stats for the Ultimate Frisbee group I play with. I'm just trying to get a basic setup for a db now and expand on it later. The end goal will able to see stats such as: which individual has the most wins, when player A and player B play together they are 10 wins and 2 losses, player A and player C only were on same team once, etc. Where I'm getting stuck is that every time we play the teams are never the same. They are constantly changing as well as the number, sometimes its 6v6 others 7v7 and so on. This is what I have so far:

```
    Player-
    playerID (pk) | name 
        1           Bob
        2           Joe
        3           Adam
        4           Sam

    Games-
    gameID (pk) | WinTeam (references Teams.TeamID) | LosingTeam (references Teams.TeamID)
        1           1                                  2
        2           4                                  3
```

and this is where I can't come up with a good solution. I would have to manually enter in the team number because the auto_increment wouldn't work... what I have is:

```
   Teams
    PlayerID (fk on Player.PlayerID) | TeamID 
       1                                 1           
       2                                 1           
       3                                 2           
       4                                 2           
       1                                 3           
       2                                 4           
       3                                 4           
       4                                 3
```

I cant come up with a good solution for keeping track of teams that are always changing. I can't do a table with 7 set columns for players because that number is changing as well.
Any advice for a first timer would help greatly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't really have a question, at least not in the question filed. I'd recommend you take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: First guess: Two entities, `Player(ID,Name)` and `Game(ID,date,location)`, and two relations `wins(Player,Game)` and `loses(Player,Game)`. If you want to know who played with who just query for a game in wins and in loses. Like it?